# Is there any video lecture based on Sheldon Ross "The first course in probability"

Tags: probability

Particularly the dicrete part.
I just found myself getting lost at why the number cases can be divided.
And all those examples and questions are too similar to tell any difference.
Just like getting a bunch of stuff out of something, rearrange etc.
And I failed to choose different method coping with different situations.

Comment: It sounds like you need to consult the live instructor of the course.

Comment: Currently getting start with self studying. So there's no instructor.

Comment: Do you have any flexibility in the choice of textbook for your self study? Some authors take a more patient and intuitive approach than others.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! I just looked up a book only talking about discrete probability in undergraduate level.

Comment: dont know if this is based on ross but sound fine https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4iyC2MNLPyQ